# Getting prod build error for ngx-owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules

i am using ngx-owl-carousel-o in my project, in local it is working fine, when i run ng build --prod getting below error, version is     `"ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^2.0.1",`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "2.0.0" it's worked for me